# How to create custom rule for a mongodb user

Tags: mongodb

How to create a mongodb user who can read write but not delete a document.

As mistakes can happen so some people may want to disable delete option for users. which can be achieved using the below tutorial.

It took me few minutes to find so sharing so it may reduce some peoples time in searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that we have to create a role.

Go to admin db

```
use admin
```

then execute the below command

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "customROle",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "addShard" ] },
       { resource: { db: "config", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert"] },
       { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "update", "insert", "find" ] }
     ],
     roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" }
     ]
   },
   { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
)
```

Note: You can give a specific db access too and give only read access or something like that.

Then we can add the role to a user by using the below command.

```
db.createUser(
{   user: "gokul",
    pwd: "gokul123",

    roles:[{role: "customROle" , db:"admin"}]})
```